# Lifetime for Rust member variable that is both kept and returned

Tags: rust

Okay, so I've got a mutable struct and I'm struggling to figure out how to understand the lifetime for what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to implement a `peek()` for an iterator. I'm aware of the `.peekable()` for iterators, but that returns a more complicated type and I don't want consumers of my iterator to have to call `.peekable()` or deal with the more complex type.

The struct looks like this:

```
enum Token {
    ...
}

struct Scanner<'a> {
    source: &'a std::str::Chars<'a>,
    lookahead: Option<Token>,
}

impl<'a> Scanner<'a> {
    pub fn peek(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // If we already have a lookahead, return it
        match self.lookahead {
            Some(t) => { return Some(t); },
            None => { },
        }

        ... // Implement obtaining the lookahead, if there is none

        self.lookahead = Some(result);  // The problem appears to be here
        return Some(result);
    }
}

impl std::iter::Iterator for Scanner {
    type Item = Token;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let result = self.peek();
        self.lookahead = None;  // The problem seems to be here
        return result;
    }
}
```

The difficulty I'm having is I can't seem to understand what the lifetime of the token Objects placed in `lookahead` should be because they both exist in `self.lookahead` and get returned from `.peek()` and `.next()`. It seems like I could potentially avoid the problem by copying the lookaheads, so one copy gets stored in the lookahead, and one copy gets returned, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I'm new to Rust, so sorry if my question doesn't make sense.

Comment: As someone asked on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78097586/type-of-stringchars), why is `Chars` a reference? Instead of `&Chars`, you could just use `Peekable<Chars<'a>>`. If you need to be able to peek multiple chars, then it might be easier just to use `text: &'a str` and `cursor: usize` and then [`CharIndicies`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/primitive.str.html#method.char_indices)

Comment: Copying a `Token` is done like copying any other type, with `clone()` or `Copy`.

Comment: Or keep the `Token` in `self` and have `peek` return a reference (with the same lifetime as the `&mut self` argument: `fn peek<'a> (&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a Self::Item>` to make sure that the `Token` isn't moved from `self` while the reference is live).